# emacs split into 3 even windows

Tags: emacs

Quick question: How do I specify the number of characters in a split window?  C-x-3 Splits my window into two windows evenly, but a subsequent split will split one of the windows in half. I'd like 3 equal sized windows.  The documentation says that I should be able to specify the number of characters for the left buffer as a parameter, but I cant seem to get that to work.  Any ideas for syntax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To specify the number of characters in the split window, do:

C-u *number-of-characters* C-x 3

Comment: Window width too small (after splitting)

Comment: The problem is it doesn't make the windows _even_, that's setting the width manually and so you'd have to count how many characters wide and tall the emacs window is to size them evenly. The answer below is more useful.

Comment: `C-x +` to make em evenly spaced

Comment: Downvoted because manual resizing. I don't want to count my terminal height and divide it by 3.

Comment: This answers the question, but Josh. F's comment and Josh Matthews' answer are what most people would like.

Answer (score 301):

`C-x 3` twice followed by `C-x +` to equally size all windows.

Comment: Is there a way to get Emacs to immediately create three equally-sized windows with one command, rather than doing `C-x 3 C-x 3 C-x +`?

Comment: @sabrewolfy make a macro

Comment: Or `C-x 2 C-x +` for horizontal splitting (good for vertical monitor)

Comment: Years of fiddling with "drag-mouse-1: resize". Our long nightmare is over.

Answer (score 17):

I have the following in my `.emacs`:

```
(defadvice split-window-horizontally (after rebalance-windows activate)
  (balance-windows))
(ad-activate 'split-window-horizontally)
```

this makes emacs call `rebalance-windows` (which is what `C-x +` is bound to by default) after every resize. It's not what I want all the time, but I want it much more often than the default behavior.

Comment: thanks for this, but I'm not sure you need the call to `(ad-activate ...)` since you included `activate` in a separate form.

Comment: I use C-x 3 for split-window-right, and this worked for me without the ad-activate:
`(defadvice split-window-right (after rebalance-windows activate)
  (balance-windows))`

Answer (score 13):

add in `.emacs`. I mapped to C-x 4, but anyone has a better idea?

```
(defun split-3-windows-horizontally-evenly ()
  (interactive)
  (command-execute 'split-window-horizontally)
  (command-execute 'split-window-horizontally)
  (command-execute 'balance-windows)
)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x 4") 'split-3-windows-horizontally-evenly)
```

Comment: I wouldn't assign that to `C-x 4`. That's the default prefix for a heap of other commands. See `C-x 4 C-h` (without setting your binding, obviously).

Comment: @phils whoa after all these years and I never knew how to get a list of commands with some common prefix... I love emacs.

Answer (score 4):

```
(defun wenshan-split-window-vertical (&optional wenshan-number)
"Split the current window into `wenshan-number' windows"
  (interactive "P")
  (setq wenshan-number (if wenshan-number
                           (prefix-numeric-value wenshan-number)
                         2))
  (while (> wenshan-number 1)
    (split-window-right)
    (setq wenshan-number (- wenshan-number 1)))
  (balance-windows))
```

This function can be used to split the current window into N windows, you can type "C-u 3 M-x wenshan-split-window-vertical" to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you use *evil* do 
`C-x 3` and then `C-w =`

Answer (score 2):

I liked @quodlibetor's solution, but it didn't work as written. This works for me (emacs 24.5)

```
(advice-add 'split-window-right :after #'balance-windows)
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems with many of the answers that use `balance-windows`here is that they may not allow the window to split due to `window-min-width` or `split-width-threshold` even if everything would be fine after rebalancing.  For example, I don't want windows less than 100 characters wide, but if I split my screen once I get two windows that are 160 characters wide and can't split again without resizing one of the windows.  I haven't figured out how to determine whether a split is good yet, so I'll probably just dynamically bind those values to 0 while splitting, and maybe do a `window-configuration-to-register` beforehand just in case so that I can recover the old layout when things go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, hope it helps:

```
(defun split-vertical-evenly ()
  (interactive)
  (command-execute 'split-window-vertically)
  (command-execute 'balance-windows))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x 2") 'split-vertical-evenly)

(defun split-horizontal-evenly ()
  (interactive)
  (command-execute 'split-window-horizontally)
  (command-execute 'balance-windows))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x 3") 'split-horizontal-evenly)
```